# Java 8, Complex groupingBy over time interval

Tags: java, mysql, java-8, java-stream

Using Java 8 + JavaFX

I am trying to do some data analysis and output my results to an XY Chart.
I've gotten my chart itself squared away, and it accepts a structure like:

```
ObservableList<Data<Timestamp, BigDecimal>>
```

My data is stored in a custom object, like so

```
public class funds{
    private long id;
    private String userName;
    private BigDecimal current;
    private Timestamp createdAt;

    ....constructors/getters/setters....
}
```

a `funds` object gets created for every user, by a recurring `Task` on a 1 minute interval.

I'd like to chart **an hourly average sum** of all `funds.current`.
So I'd normally sum up each minute for all users, and then avg that for each hour. In MySQL I can do this:

```
SELECT FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at)/(60*60)) AS hour, AVG(current)
FROM (
    SELECT FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at)/60) AS minute, SUM(current) as current, created_at
    FROM funds
    GROUP BY minute
) as table1
GROUP BY hour;
```

But in this instance, I don't have direct SQL access, and must use java. I have tried looking at streams and the `Collectors.groupingBy`, but I cannot wrap my head around it enough to get what I want.

Also the `Collectors` seem to not have any functions for use with **BigDecimal**, which I need, as doubles are completely terrible for financial data.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I suggest the way to learn this is to make some simple test cases to experiment with the various `groupingBy()` collectors to see what they do and how you can use them.  Start with a small stream of data representing your inner select's table (`funds`) and try to accomplish only the inner select.  Then pass that result to another `groupingBy()` for the outer select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really don't want to use doubles, try this:

```
Map<Long, BigDecimal> hourAverages = funds.stream()
    //group by minute; as a result we have Map<Long, BigDecimal>
    .collect(toMap(f -> f.createdAt.getTime() / 6000, f -> f.current, BigDecimal::add))
    .entrySet().stream()
    //group by hours; here we use BigDecimal[] to store sum and count; 
    //as a result we have Map<Long, BigDecimal[]>
    .collect(groupingBy(e -> e.getKey() / 60,
            collectingAndThen(
                    reducing(new BigDecimal[] {BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.ZERO},
                        e -> new BigDecimal[]{e.getValue(), BigDecimal.ONE},
                        (a, b) -> new BigDecimal[]{a[0].add(b[0]), a[1].add(b[1])}),
                    //finally divide by count
                    a -> a[0].divide(a[1], BigDecimal.ROUND_UP))));
```

Comment: Wow, looks nice. One thing I wonder: Shouldn't the identity value for the second `reducing` be `new BD[] {BD.ZERO, BD.ZERO}` instead of `new BD[] {BD.ZERO, BD.ONE}`? Otherwise, a list with 1 element ends up with count 2, doesn't it?

Comment: Why the downvote? Maybe something is wrong or I can improve something?